# How to show the Outlook email attachment preview for a specified attachment

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, email-attachments, outlook-2013

I have a custom pane for emails in Outlook 2013, using VSTO. It lists the attachments in a `ListView` and allows conversion operations to be performed on the attachments:

[image]

The user can normally press on an attachment to get a preview pane for the selected attachment. I need to duplicate that preview action when the matching attachment is selected in *my* ListView. This will allow them to select one attachment, see the preview, then choose which type of document it is (ID doc, CV etc) without having to move back and forth between my custom panel and the usual list of attachments.

I have Googled various terms, but this seems to too obscure to find. I am hoping there is an Outlook 2013 VSTO expert out there that will know where to start with this. The `Inspector.AttachmentSelection` is a starting point, but that is *read-only*.

My C# selection change handler is shown below (all error checking removed to simplify it):

```
private void listview_SelectedIndexChanged(object( sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListView listView = sender as ListView;
     ListViewItem listViewItem = listView.SelectedItems[0];
     Attachment attachment = lvi.Tag as Attachment;
     Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();

     // How to preview the attachment in the inspector???
}
```

**Update:**

As a fallback, I am able to go the other way, by catching the `Inspector.AttachmentSelectionChange` event as shown below and selecting items in my `ListView`, but I would prefer to be able to select the attachments from my `ListView` and that cause the `AttachmentSelection` to change:

```
    void inspector_AttachmentSelectionChange()
    {
        this.attachmentListView.SelectedItems.Clear();
        foreach (Attachment selection in this.Inspector.AttachmentSelection)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in this.attachmentListView.Items)
            {
                if (item.Tag as Attachment == selection)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's nothing in the Outlook Object Model (or Redemption) that allows you to set the selected attachment.

However, it may be possible to select it using some Win32API commands to set the focus on the attachment selector region.  If you use Spy++ you can see that it has a specific window handle (0007096E; AfxWndW).  When that window is activated, you could issue TAB keystroke commands to select an attachment.  I'm not sure though how to activate a specific attachment; TAB seems to be the only keyboard command in use for that window.

Comment: Although I have considerable experience with automating Windows messages, to simulate interactions, the "specific" window handle is not specific and the class name `AfxWndW` is common among other controls in Outlook. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can walk through the windows stack from some of the known window handles in Outlook to get to that specific subwindow - I've done that before to issue keystrokes to the "SuperGrid".